# CSCart could not automatically display order details and empty cart

Tags: shopping-cart, cs-cart

I attempted to create a new payment method which was mostly successful except the portion when the payment gateway redirects user back to the merchant homepage and the homepage simply displays an "Order Successful" message but does not list out the order details below the Order Successful message. The user have to manually click to check their order details.

The second problem related to the failure to automatically display the order details when users get redirected back is the cart simply refuses to automatically empty itself after the order process is successful and the user has to personally empty their own carts.

May I know how I should resolve these related issues ?

Below is the payment gateway script:

```
if ($mode == 'notify' && !empty($_REQUEST['order_id'])) {
    if (fn_check_payment_script('Testbank.php', $_REQUEST['order_id'], $processor_data)) {
        $pp_response = array();
        //Update order status
        if ($_POST['Order_Status'] == 'YES') { // Succeed
            $pp_response['order_status'] = "P";
            $pp_response['transaction_id'] = $_POST['Order_RefNo'];
            $pp_response['reason_text'] = '';
            fn_finish_payment($_POST['order_id'], $pp_response);
            //fn_order_placement_routines($_POST['order_id']);

        } else {
            // If fail ...
            $pp_response['order_status'] = "G"; //Verifying payment
            $pp_response['transaction_id'] = $_POST['TM_RefNo'];
            $pp_response['reason_text'] = $_POST['TM_Error'];           
            fn_change_order_status($_POST['order_id'], $pp_response['order_status']);   
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to comment and uncomment the fn_order_placement_routines but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the second problem you can add this line after the fn_finish_payment function:

fn_order_placement_routines($order_id);

That will empty your cart and send the notifications to customers.